# Comparing two pandas dataframes with different integer types

Tags: python, pandas

I just ran into some weird behaviour comparing the values of two pandas dataframes using `pd.Dataframe.equals()`:

## Comparison 1

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]})
df2 = df1.copy()

df1.equals(df2)
# True (obviously)
```

However, when I change the column type to a different integer format, they will not be considered equal anymore:

```
df1['a'] = df1['a'].astype(np.int32)
df1.equals(df2)
# False
```

In the `.equals()` documentation, they point out that the variables must have the same type, and present an example comparing floats to integers, which doesn't work. I didn't expect this to extend to different types of integers, too.

## Comparison 2

When doing the same comparison using `==`, it does return `True`:

```
(df1 == df2).all().all()   
# True
```

However, `==` doesn't assess two missing values as equal to each other.

## My question

Is there an elegant way to handle missing values as equal, whilst not enforcing the same integer type? The best I can come up with is:

```
(df1.fillna(0) == df2.fillna(0)).all().all()
```

but there has to be a more concise and less hacky way to deal with this problem.

My follow up, opinion-based question: Would you consider this a bug?

Comment: In my opinion your current solution is fine. To answer your question about this being a bug. It would be indeed more convenient if  `.eq` method would consider different integer types the same, that said, I wouldn't see it at as a bug perse, more a missing feature.

Comment: Does `equals` yield `True` for `NaN`? That is definitely new for me. Beside, I don't think you can have `int32` data type with `NaN`.

Comment: you could try to set the type of `df2` according to the type of `df1` with `astype`, `df1.equals(df2.astype(df1.dtypes))` gives `True` and the `Nan` should be still handled

Comment: What's the problem in enforcing the same integer type?
You can use `pd.to_numeric(df, downcast='something', errors='coerce')` on both, and it is relatively fast.

Comment: @QuangHoang `equals()` returns `True` for comparing two missing values.

Comment: comparing is not as hazardous as assigning.  assign requires downcasting.  comparing should not require any conversion. if an int32 and int64 are not consider equal for 1 and 1 than I think it is a bug.

Answer (score 2):

If you think of this as a decimal problem (i.e. does 2 equal 2) then this perhaps looks like a bug. However, if you look at it from how the interpreter sees it (i.e. does 00000010 equal 0000000000000010) then it becomes plain that there is indeed a difference. Bitwise operations.

From a validation perspective, it is probably a good idea to make sure you are comparing apples to apples and so I like the answer of @Ben.T:

```
df1.equals(df2.astype(df1.dtypes))
```

Is this a bug? That is above my pay grade. You can submit it, and the thinkers surrounding the pandas library can make a decision. It does seem odd that the '==' operator gives different results that the '.equals' function and that may sway the decision.